Uniswap V3 transaction on Optimism reverted with "err32" error
I was attempting to interact with a Uniswap V3 pool contract on the Optimism network, but encountered a transaction failure with an 'err32' error. The transaction reverted with the warning:
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]

Transaction Details are as follows:
Transaction Hash: 0x1edfa68af92a936e09a23a85729f1396c616d6411ecce17998a4c17043ef8c64
From Address: 0x31d85b60b67d9eb687b7b376a889164a5713e69d
Uniswap V3 Pool Contract Address: 0x8d653ea5de3ff7786575ffe062309e8cd1bb0d0f
Attempted to trade 0 ETH.
I constructed a transaction to interact with the pool contract's swap() function, passing in the necessary parameters. The transaction was submitted successfully, but reverted with the 'err32' error.
Can anyone shed light on what this 'err32' error signifies in the context of a Uniswap V3 pool transaction on Optimism? Is this typically an issue with the pool contract itself, the passed parameters, or something else?

Can you share the code snippet that you used to construct the transaction ?

If 0x8D653Ea5De3ff7786575ffe062309e8cd1Bb0D0F is a pool address why isn't the creation transaction to a v3 factory contract? I don't recognise the function sig being called on it as from a v3 pool, and I can't seem to make a read call using ABI for a v3 call to it, can you? Is it a proxy for swaps?
